# Draggable element falls through the droppable DIV in front another droppable element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I use jquery to realise drag & drop in my small application.
The wireframe looks like this:
[image: Wireframe]

now when I drag a element (`<div>`) to the small, fixed `<div id="zbox">` the draggable element falls trouth to the droppable element with `class="day"` in the background.

This is the code of the zbox in the front

```
$("#zbox").droppable({
    greedy: true,
    activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        //DO SOMETHING  
    }
});
```

Comment: a jsFiddle would be helpfull.. css? maybe some z-index problems?

Comment: thanks, but the zbox is always in the front and has as the onle element a z-index = 100000.

Comment: whre is the zbox? inside a .day maybe? really hard to help without a jsFiddle or example or markup..